# Preprocessor macro without replacement C++

Tags: c++, macros

According to cplusplus.com, the syntax to define a macro is:

```
#define identifier replacement
```

However, I sometimes stumble upon a macro definition which doesn't contain a replacement. For example in afxwin.h, there is the following preprocessor definition:

```
#define afx_msg         // intentional placeholder
```

My questions:

1. What happens at compile-time when a preprocessor definition that doesn't have a replacement is used? Is it simply ignored? For example, does the line `afx_msg void OnAddButton();` become `void OnAddButton();`?
2. What is the purpose of using preprocessor without replacement? Is it simply to make code more clear?

Comment: When you tried it out, wheat did you discover?

Comment: You can just think of `#define` as a simple search and replace function applied before compilation. Just try doing a search for afx_msg and replace them with nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Nothing" (no text) is a valid replacement text for a macro. It will simply be removed (more precisely, replaced by nothing) by the preprocessor.

There are multiple reasons why you'd use something like this. One is to simply use the macro in `#ifdef` and similar constructrs.

Another is conditional compilation. A typical use case is public APIs and DLL exports. On Windows, you need to mark a function as exported from a DLL (when building the DLL) or as imported from a DLL (when linking against the DLL). On ELF systems, no such declarations are necessary. Therefore, you'll often see code like this in public library headers:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #ifdef BUILDING_MYLIB
     #define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
     #define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#else
  #define MYLIB_API
#endif

void MYLIB_API myApiFunction();
```

Yet another reason could be code processing tools. Perhaps you have a tool which parses source code, extracting a list of functions with a certain marker. You can define such a marker as an empty macro.

Answer (score 5):

```
#define bla
```

simply defines `bla`.

you can use it with

```
#ifdef bla
...
place some code here
...
#endif
```

a typical use case is `#define DEBUG` to enable special code parts in debugging mode.

Another way to set such things from "outside" is:

```
 g++ -DDEBUG x.cpp
```

which also sets the macro DEBUG defined.

And every header file should have something like:

```
#ifndef THIS_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD
#define THIS_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD
...
rest of header file
...
#endif
```

This simply protects your header file for (recursivly) read more the once.

Some can be done with implementation specific `#pragma once`.

Answer (score 1):

1. the preprocessor processes it, removing it and replacing it with nothing
2. could be a variety of reasons, including readability, portability, custom compiler features, etc.